# The Android keyboard is changing the components of ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a layout with ConstraintLayout as root, and this layout belongs to a Fragment shown in a ViewPager2, hosted by a Activity that extends FragmentActivity. My Problem is that every time the keyboard is up, it doesnt overlap the layout, it makes the window smaller, changing the aspect of my layout.

ViewPager layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.WelcomeActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/welcome_viewPager2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator3
    android:id="@+id/welcome_indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view5"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/welcome_btnLogar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/welcome_btnLogar"
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparentBlack"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/welcome_btnRegister"
    style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparentBlack"
    android:text="@string/create_an_account"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view5" />
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.CadastroActivity">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_ame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_android_gray_24dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputEdit_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_email"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_ame"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_email_gray_24dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputEdit_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_lock_open_gray_24dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:helperText="@string/min_6_characters"
    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/colorAccentWelcome"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_email"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputEdit_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_confirmPassword"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/confirm_your_password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_password"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputEdit_confirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cadastro_frag1_btnNextStep"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/go_to_next_step"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_btn_all_round_welcome_accent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_confirmPassword" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
    android:text="@string/step_1_2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccentWelcome"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cadastro_frag1_inputLayout_ame"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

How can i make the keyboard overlap the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `AndroidManifest.xml` add `windowSoftInputMode`

```
 <activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

or programatically

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft)

> - The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention.

> - The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether it is resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether its contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the window is covered by the soft keyboard.

If you need to scroll the page when the keyboard is open, add your ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- xml code-->
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```